# How can I show run time logging in a springboot based web project?

Tags: spring-boot, logback

Now I am developing a web project with springboot v1.5.9.
But now I am facing a problem is that , I have a requirement to show the runtime and realtime logging in the web page . 
the details are:
1.Now I am using logback as logging framework and use a HTML layout to output to a HTML format log file .which can show log info in a pretty format
2.the file is located outside the executable jar , and generated at run time , dymically

My Question is that :
How to set springboot to "redirect" to "load" that HTML file and show it to user ?
Any other better practice can fulfill this requirement ?

Thanks

Comment: See if [spring-boot-admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) is suffice

Comment: Thanks for response but for the logs I seperated in different logger output files so I am afraid this solution is not suiltable for me